# Create date headers similar to reputation changes using React js

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am trying to create headings just like reputation changes at the top of this site. I use react js and next js.

Here is code sandbox demo I created.

https://codesandbox.io/s/react-array-map-xn316

The output I want is:

**Last Hour**

- content 1
- content 2
- content 3

**Today**

- content 4

**Older**

- content 5

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your if-else logic is not going to give you the correct headers and you're squashing them on the top-level `else`.  You get the right headers with

```
    let listHeader = "--";
    if (time === "none") {
        if (hour) {
            setTime("hour");
        } else if (day) {
            setTime("day");
        } else {
            setTime("older");
        }
    } else {
        if (hour) {
            listHeader = "Last Hour";
        } else if (day) {
            listHeader = "Today";
        } else {
            listHeader = "Older";
        }
    }
```

You have no groupings for things in the header, so the way you're returning it isn't quite what you want.  The following code is an example on how to do that

```
import React from "react";
import "./App.css";

const useLoadData = () => {
    const data = [
        {id: "01", content: "content 1", time: "3 seconds ago"},
        {id: "02", content: "content 2", time: "4 minutes ago"},
        {id: "03", content: "content 3", time: "35 minutes ago"},
        {id: "04", content: "content 4", time: "3 hours ago"},
        {id: "05", content: "content 5", time: "4 days ago"}
    ];
    //item 1 should get a heading "Last hour"
    //item 2 and item 3 should not get a heading. They are also under "Last hour"
    //item 4 should get a heading "Today"
    return data;
};

function findListHeader(item) {
    let timeC = item.time

    let listHeader = "--";
    let hour = false;
    let day = false;
    if (timeC.includes("second") || timeC.includes("minute")) {
        hour = true;
    }
    if (timeC.includes("hour")) {
        day = true;
    }
    if (hour) {
        listHeader = "Last Hour";
    } else if (day) {
        listHeader = "Today";
    } else {
        listHeader = "Older";
    }
    return {header: listHeader, item};
}

export default function App() {
    const var1 = useLoadData();

    let headers = ["Last Hour", "Today", "Older"]
    const itemHeaders = var1.map((itemP) => findListHeader(itemP));

    const var2 = headers.map((header) =>
        <CommentOne
            key={header}
            header={header}
            items={itemHeaders
                .filter(itemWithHeader => itemWithHeader.header === header)
                .map(itemWithHeader => itemWithHeader.item)
            }
        />);

    return <div> {var2} </div>;
}

function CommentOne({header, items}) {
    let content = items.map(item => <p>{item.content}</p>)
    return (
        <div className="App">
            <h1>{header}</h1>
            {content}
        </div>
    );
}
```

Comment: Awesome. Voted up and trying it out.

Comment: It works well but leaves empty headers when there are no items under it.

Comment: The headers are predefined first so there will always be orphan headers if there are no items under it. `let headers = ["Last Hour", "Today", "Older"]` - This will look for items that belong to these headers. I will play with this and post an updated answer based on your answer.